# Gradle exclude one project from another

Tags: gradle

i'm faced with dependency excluding trouble on Gradle 2.5
So, i've 3 project

First one a moduleB (build.gradle) :

```
group 'com.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}


dependencies {
    compile project(':moduleA')
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.test.Main'
    }
    doFirst {
        from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    }
}
```

moduleA project :

```
group 'com.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile project(':moduleC')
}
```

and moduleC project

```
group 'com.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations.all {
    transitive = false
}
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile project(':moduleB')
}
```

moduleC need use some class from moduleB, but moduleC should not include moduleA via moduleB (transitive dependency), i try use transitive = false but it not work for me. 
How to exclude moduleA if i want use moduleB from moduleC ?

My gradle error :

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:moduleA:classes
\--- :moduleA:compileJava
     +--- :moduleA:jar
     |    \--- :moduleA:classes (*)
     +--- :moduleB:jar
     |    \--- :moduleB:classes
     |         \--- :moduleB:compileJava
     |              +--- :moduleA:jar (*)
     |              +--- :moduleB:jar (*)
     |              \--- :moduleC:jar
     |                   \--- :moduleC:classes
     |                        \--- :moduleC:compileJava
     |                             +--- :moduleA:jar (*)
     |                             +--- :moduleB:jar (*)
     |                             \--- :moduleC:jar (*)
     \--- :moduleC:jar (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

Why this not work for me ? that's a bug of Gradle or whatever?

```
compile(project(':moduleB')) {
        transitive = false
    }
```

Comment: Could you please try `exclude` instead of `transitive = false`?

Comment: I'm try to use this:
compile(project(':moduleB')) {
        exclude module:':moduleA'
}
that not work too

Comment: Then it seems you need to rearrange your project structure.

Comment: So, that impossible ? or not? (i mean exclude)

Comment: To be honest I suppose it's possible, however unfortunately I've no time to do trial and error, so I'd just rearrange the project structure.

Comment: anyone can help me ? please

Comment: Is that project hosted online?

Comment: https://github.com/sample-git-user/gradle here u get that test project